# Can't add product to compare, _validateFormKey() return false

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, compare, form-key

I'm updating an old Magento instance from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.1 (I know there is the v. 1.9.2.2).

I'm also using the Ultimo theme, but i tested the bug also with the standard RWD theme that comes with Magento 1.9.

The issue is about the add to compare button: it doesn't work. It only redirects me to the same page but it doesn't add the product to compare list.

I find out that the problem is in the addAction() function in CompareController.php

There is

```
public function addAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
                $this->_redirectReferer();
                return;
            }
...
}
```

And $this->_validateFormKey() return FALSE so nothing is done.

Just for information, my add to compare link are looking like the following

```
http://example.com/catalog/product_compare/add/product/2480/uenc/aHR0cDovL3N0a25ldzE5Lmh0dGRldi5pdC9pcGhvbmUtNi1wbHVzLTE2Z2ItYmxhY2suaHRtbA,,/
```

At the moment, my solution is to comment the IF.

Somebody knows how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
Into the template file addto.phtml the code is the following:

```
...
<?php
    $_compareUrl = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product);
?>
<?php if($_compareUrl) : ?>

    <li>
        <a class="link-compare feature feature-icon-hover first" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?>">
            <span class="ic ic-compare ib icon-color-productview"></span>
            <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></span>
        </a>
    </li>

<?php endif; ?>
...
```

Comment: I suggest you post your edit as an answer and accept it, since it seems to have solved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an old overload in the local folder for the Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare Class, so it has not the new FORM_KEY feature in the function getAddUrl().

Thanks to @Akhilesh Patel

Comment: great!! you can accept my answer as well if that help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change compare URL in your phtml

```
<?php
    $_compareUrl = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product);
?>
```

This code will give you the right compare URL for your product.

**If this will not work show your phtml code which have compare link.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my code is already this.

Comment: actually compare url should be like catalog/product_compare/add/product/2480/uenc/aHR0cDovL2NjY2Rlc2t0b3AuY29tL3RlYW0vYWtoaWxlc2gvbWFnZTE5L2xhZmF5ZXR0ZS1jb252ZXJ0aWJsZS1kcmVzcy5odG1s/form_key/jHkteueHaz064EL8/ and in your case it is not adding this form_key in URL. try to debug in class Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare

Comment: Found!!! Thanks for the advise... I have an overload in local/ for the Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare class.